# SQL Server 2008: New Domain user rights issue

Tags: sql-server-2008, permissions, ssms

I have a SQL Server 2008 installed on Windows Server.

The problem I am facing is when I create a new user in windows, and then add that user in SQL Server Logins [`Domain\Username`] with Windows authentication, and give access to one database `[inventory]`.

When the user logs in into SSMS, and when s/he expands the object explorer, he get an error message:

> The server principal "Domain\User" is not able to access the database "Payments" under the current security context.
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 916)

If I give access to the `Payments` database, the user is able to see the database list in the object browser.

I do not want to give access to the `Payments` database.

Please help.

Mansoor

Comment: Did you by any chance define `Payments` as the **default database** for those logins? In that case, when they log in, those users would be attempted to be sent to their defined default database - to which they don't have access. **Solution:** set the `Inventory` database as the default for these logins.

Comment: @marc_s, thanks for such a prompt response... No, when i created the login in SSMS, I just gave access to the user for the inventory database only, like db_owner only, nothing else...

Comment: and, no, the database is not set to default database